# Passing data to an ancestor component vue3

Tags: vue.js, components, vuejs3, emit, vue-props

I have a multi-step form in Vue3 that has the following structure:

```html
<Formroot />
    ...
    <formPage2 />
    ... 
       <postcodeWidget />
```

I have a data structure in my formRoot that holds all the field values from the child components and then uses them to make an external API call and present a result.

I use Props to pass the data down to the child components and then emit from the children to the parent.

The issue is, my autocomplete widget - which pulls from an external api - does all the autocomplete in the `setup()` function. I cannot figure out the best way to communicate input from that widget back up to the formRoot component.

I tried emitting from the widget but I can't access the instance from within setup, and I can't seem to access the data from setup variables within an instance method.

For example, I have a function called changePostcode that fires on input to the field:

```js
methods: {
        changePostcode(e){
            //I have tried calling the input event:
            this.$emit('update:postcode', e.target.value)
            //I have tried accessing my setup variable:
            this.$emit('update:postcode', this.selectedPostcode) //or postcode.value this is the actull value I want to emit.
            //these dont work.They return nothing. 
        },
}
```

my selectedPostcode variable is set in the setup() function as follows:

```js
setup() {
    ...
    let selectedPostcode = ref('')
    let searchTerm = ref('')
    ...
    // searchTerm is used in a filter with data from an external API to offer suggestions. This is the ultimate source of the "location" object
    const selectPostcode = (location) => {
        selectedPostcode.value = location.postcode
        searchTerm.value = location.locality
    }
    return {
        searchTerm,
        ...
        selectPostcode,
        selectedPostcode,
        ...
    }
}
```

I have a locality and a postcode variable because I want to populate the input with a "locality" that includes the full name of the suburb while I want to emit only the post/zip code.

My setup does a bunch of other work including calling and api for a list of suburb and filtering on user input to make suggestions. That all works fine.

In summary,

1. A multi step form
2. One step includes a nested component that needs to pass data up to the root ancestor
3. I cannot seem to access/emit data from setup() back up to the ancestor element

What is the right way to do this? It seems like it should be a pretty common use case.

I looked into `provide/inject` as well but I also couldn't understand how to send data back up to the ancestor only down to the child.

Comment: Why not have an external `export const store = reactive({ foo: 'bar' })` which you `import { store } from 'path/to/store'` in both ancestor and child? Any component modifying it (e.g: `store.foo = 'baz'`) will trigger a real-time change in any other component importing the same reactive object, regardless of the relation between the components. The only case when you don't want that is if this child/ancestor relation is repeated in a list. In that case, you want to use `provide/inject`, as @tony suggested.

Comment: Btw, I don't recommend using reactive objects as stores. By comparison, you're better off using actual stores (e.g: `pinia`). But reactive objects are still more straight-forward than prop drilling + chain emitting, or provide/inject, IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ancestor could [`provide`](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-dependency-injection.html#provide) a function (e.g., a setter) that the nested component could [`inject`](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-dependency-injection.html#inject) to communicate a value back to the ancestor:

```html
// RootAncestor.vue
<script setup>
import { ref, provide } from 'vue'

const postCode = ref('initial value')
const setPostCode = value => {
  postCode.value = value
}

provide('setPostCode', setPostCode)
</script>
```

```html
// NestedComponent.vue
<script setup>
import { inject } from 'vue'

const setPostCode = inject('setPostCode')

const save = () => {
  setPostCode('12345')
}
</script>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-update-ancestor-from-nested-component?file=src%2FApp.vue)

Comment: I didn't realise I needed a settier in the ancestor, that works great.

Comment: Is it better to do all component communication through either provide/inject OR props or can it be mixed and matched within an individual project? Are there performance implications to having both used for handling component communicaton? Aside from more confusing code for other to read?

Comment: One last follow-up. How can I reset the const variable from outside the setup function in the ancestor during a form reset? It does not seem to allow this. I'm destroying the cached child so the value is gone in the form but it persists in the ancestor.